# Using Ruby on share web hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, sass, compass-sass

We are developing a Wordpress theme and we are going to publish it on themeforest.com. We are using Sass(scss Syntax) as our CSS Preprocessor and we need to compile it on server side.

We have two solutions:

- Use [phpsass](https://github.com/richthegeek/phpsass) which is a php script(but it has some bugs)
- Use Ruby Compiler which most of [wordpress plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/sass) use this

I noticed that plugins which use Ruby need to have PHP proc_open function enabled on server.

My question is what are Pros and Cons of using Ruby compiler on servers? and are most of shared web hosts support Ruby and have PHP proc_open function enabled by default?

Comment: Can't you just precompile sass to css and publish that (compiled css)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, the right way to do that !

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No we change sass variable with our theme option and it needs to be compiled every time theme option has been saved.

Comment: Maybe a better solution would be to just change the class of the body element?

Comment: @Parhum: does it mean that I have to have **ruby** in order to use your theme for a **PHP-based** blog engine? It's a deal breaker (for me, at least). Sass is a pleasure to work with, I agree. But as a customer (user) of your product, I couldn't care less about your pleasure.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm agree with you, we could use Less instead but using sass has some extra features(like Extends and Control Directives) that are very useful for our customers and we are going to explain these benefits to them.

Comment: I found a php library that support all features without bug: http://leafo.net/scssphp/
I decide to use it and forget ruby compiler for php user!